# How to read single file with multiple instances in java and Java EE

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I am having a file `sub.srt` and am reading that using multiple instances simultaneously. It works fine. Is this possible to work same in web application with Servlets and JSP?

This is the main file

```
public class SingleTest 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    String s[]= new String[10];

    for(int i = 1;i<=10;i++)

        {
         SingleFileThread sft1 = new SingleFileThread(i); 
         sft1.start();
        }
}

}
```

This is the Thread to create multiple instances to read a single file

```
public class SingleFileThread extends Thread 
 {
public int t =0;
public SingleFileThread(int i)
{
    t = i;
}
  public void run()
   {
   try{
      File f = new File("E:\\Leo-Softwares\\workspace\\SingleFileThread     \\src\\test\\sub.srt");
      System.out.println("f.setReadOnly() :"+f.setReadOnly());
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(f);
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
      String strLine;
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
          System.out.println ("Thread :"+t+"_____"+strLine);
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      }

      in.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get you?? Y u need to implement **threads** in **jsp**..What you exactly want to do..Because the tomcat container itself maintains the threads for your concern jsp.. What u want is may be about the **session tracking** i guess..Sorry but didn,t get your question properly...???

Comment: Please help me ,I am having single file(txt) in my webapplicaton (tomcat6) but now that file is used by instance in app.but is this possible to read the same file using another instance?.will it be problem? this is running in production.

Comment: @sunleo ok so you want to read same file with in a session.. once it is already in use.. I dn think still you need to create threads for that.. But again if you want it will work..

Comment: But again it depends on the environment you are working on..Like in EJB its not just discouraged to use thread but it is forbidden infact.. So just be careful while using it. as it hampers the already spawned thread process may be!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It will work means fine.but we are not having EJB, just webapplication which is running in Tomcat6(webserver).

Comment: ok. if you are not using any frameworks then u might use it..but still need to be careful..Don't make the thread starve :) :)!! Happy Programming i must say..

Comment: Thanks once again for your wonderful support and help.I got it.